# rapidxml first_node doesn't return null

Tags: c++, xml, null, rapidxml

I'm trying to parse a XML file using RapidXML in C++, the file is like:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>1111</b>
        <c>
            <d1>2222</d1>       
            <d2>3333</d2>
        </c>
    </a>
</root>
```

To identify the parent nodes I'm doing:

```
if (currentNode->first_node() != 0) { // this node has children, search for them }
```

It works fine for the two first nodes (root and a) but when I do this for node 'b' it returns a pointer to somewhere instead of 0, but 'b' doesn't have child nodes. Shouldn't it return 0? The RapidXML documentation says:

**function xml_node::first_node
Synopsis**

```
xml_node<Ch>* first_node(const Ch *name=0, std::size_t name_size=0, bool case_sensitive=true) const;
```

**Description**
Gets first child node, optionally matching node name.

**Parameters
name**
    Name of child to find, or 0 to return first children regardless of its name; this string doesn't have to be zero-terminated if name_size is non-zero

**name_size**
    Size of name, in characters, or 0 to have size calculated automatically from string

**case_sensitive**
    Should name comparison be case-sensitive; non case-sensitive comparison works properly only for ASCII characters

**Returns**
Pointer to found child, or 0 if not found.

Any idea why this is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I know in other XML implementations the value of the <b> node would be a "value" node itself.   ie: b has a child node, which is the value 1111.  Not sure if RapidXML is the same implementation or not.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, now that you mentioned that, I tried to read the value of the nodes. Value of node b is 1111 and 1111 is also identified as a child node of b and the value of this child node is also 1111, altough it doesn't have a name, what is right.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused between XML 'element nodes', (i.e. root, a, b, etc..) and RapidXML's 'parser nodes', produced by the parser - which includes data nodes.

You can either look at the node's [`type()`](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#classrapidxml_1_1xml__node_975e86937621ae4afe6a423219de30d0_1975e86937621ae4afe6a423219de30d0) to determine if it's a data node, or use the [`parse_no_data_nodes`](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_87e8bbab53702cf3b438bd553c10b6b9_187e8bbab53702cf3b438bd553c10b6b9) parsing flag.

Answer (score 0):

From Rapidxml documentation

```
   enum node_type
   ...
    Values

    node_document     A document node. Name and value are empty.
    node_element      An element node. Name contains element name.
                      Value contains text of first data node.
    node_data         A data node. Name is empty. Value contains data text.
    node_cdata        A CDATA node. Name is empty. Value contains data text.
    node_comment      A comment node. Name is empty. Value contains comment text.
    node_declaration  A declaration node. Name and value are empty. Declaration 
                      parameters (version, encoding and standalone) are 
                      in node attributes.
    node_doctype      A DOCTYPE node. Name is empty. Value contains DOCTYPE text.
    node_pi           A PI node. Name contains target. Value contains instructions.
```

so as pointed by Roddy you should check the "rapidXML" type of node. In your example doing something like

```
    if (currentNode->first_node() != 0 && currentNode->type () == node_element) 
    { 
        // this node has children, search for them 
    }
```